# modprobe -k -q (missing parameter)

Tags: linux, kernel-module, modprobe

well, I got the following modprobe scripts

```
modprobe -k -q streams
```

what does the -k parameter mean ?.
is it exist in older modprobe ?
I don't see -k parameter in recent modprobe.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-k` flag in older `modprobe` versions was used to set the `autoclean` flag on loaded modules. The autoclean flag was part of a mechanism in the kernel that allowed loaded modules that had not been used for a while to be unloaded automatically. If you listed loaded kernel modules on such a system, you could easily tell which modules were loaded with the autoclean bit set by looking for the `(autoclean)` tag somewhere on the line for the listed module.

The `-k` flag is missing from recent `modprobe` versions. I cannot say with certainty whether the use of this feature has been depreciated in recent kernel.

You could look at the manpage for an older version of modprobe [here](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/8modprobe.man.html). And [this](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/custom-guide/ch-kernel-modules.html), and [this](http://linux.about.com/od/lkm_howto/a/hwtlkm06t03_2.htm) mention the autoclean flag.

Comment: I have the following scripts 

"modprobe -k -q -- streams"

what does it mean exactly ?

Comment: If you read the manpage and the articles I linked to, you should be able to figure it out easily.